# run a remote batch file as domain administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008

I just inherited a new job that is so bad the last IT company just walked out after a few days.

I need to remotely do 20 things from a win 2012R2 server, but I can't get to step one yet. I can't seem to get the syntax down. I want to put a simple batch file on the public share F: and run it as full administrator rights.

INSIDE OF THE DOMAIN LOGIN SCRIPT:

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")
oShell.run "f:\psexec \\* -u BW\administrator -p PaSSw0rd F:\adddomainuser.bat"
```

THIS IS THE CONTENTS OF `F:\adddomainuser.bat`

```
net localgroup administrators "BW\Domain Users" /add
```

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that would be better handled by GPO rather than by logon script.  [Doesn't it?](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/907-gpo-to-push-out-local-administrators-across-a-domain)

Comment: Are you sure that the `psexec` executable is located in `f:\` ?
Second, are you really sure you want to add **every** domain user to the local admin group on that machine ?

Comment: Yes. The real important / confidential stuff is locked down by Group membership. I just can't get the script to run.